# How to read and display data from a CO2 logger connected via RS-232?

Tags: arduino, serial

I got a Licor CO2-Logger (Li-820) for a scientific experiment. The Li-820 outputs an analog signal (voltage) and also offers a serial communication via a RS-232 port. I would like to sniff the serial communication with an [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) and display the CO2 values on a LCD display such that I can control the analog signal that is logged in a computer system. I want to display both the analog and the digital signal.

I use a RS-232 level shifter to connect the Licor CO2 analyzer to the Arduino Uno, and I can sniff the COM port successfully both with the Arduino serial monitor and a sniffer program.
Over the RS-232 port the Li-820 device outputs an XML-like line that is as follows (Line breaks and indentation added for readability):

```xml
<li820>
  <data>
    <celltemp>5.1252350e1</celltemp>
    <cellpres>9.7159633e1</cellpres>
    <co2>5.2527637e2</co2>
    <co2abs>7.7893261e-2</co2abs>
    <ivolt>1.1386718e1</ivolt>
    <raw>3950702,3808028</raw>
  </data>
</li820>
```

I would like to parse that information for the relevant part with the Arduino Uno which is the `<co2>5.2527637e2</co2>` ("CO2" value) and first output it to the serial monitor. Next, I will display that value on a LCD display. This last step should be a minor problem.

So, how can I parse the information for the relevant bits and then display it to the serial monitor?

I looked into many examples on the Internet. [A modified version of the working code from here](http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1287446626) was the closest I got.

Comment: This is a software problem and does not belong in this forum.  I suspect stackover flow might be a better place to ask the question but am not sure...

Comment: I think you find more subject matter experts at stackoverflow, maybe migrate the question to it.

Comment: This question is being worked with on an arduino, this seems like a boundary question but one that fits on either site. If it continues to not get attention I am willing to migrate.

Comment: See if arduino gives you a sscanf() which works with floating point types or even scientific notation.  If not you will have to use an integer solution with a denominator you can grow.  Break the problem down into pieces - finding the right value, then reading it in.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you can already read the string into a buffer so I will start at the buffer. Your code should go something like this (you will need to import [the string library](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject)):

```
String wholeString = String(yourLoadedCharBuffer);
int startTag = wholeString.indexOf("<co2>");
int endTag = wholeString.indexOf("</co2>");

String co2FullString = wholeString.substring(startTag+5,endTag-1);
```

This gives us "5.2527637e2", you add 5 to the start tag because it is 4 characters long and you want to start at the "5", and you subtract 1 from the endtag, because we don't want the first character of it.

```
int eStart = co2FullString.indexOf("e");
String decimalString = co2FullString.substring(0,eStart-1);
String powerString = co2FullString.substring(estart+1, co2FullString.length-1);

char decimalCharArray[] = decimalString.toCharArray();
char powerCharArray[] = powerString.toCharArray();

float decimal = atof(&decimalCharArray[0]);
float power = atof(&powerCharArray[0]);

float finalCO2Value = pow(decimal,power);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be obvious to you, but the output is being sent in XML format.  Getting an XML parsing library for arduino will go a long way to meeting your needs.

Comment: Technically correct, but probably a bit overweight for the problem at hand where likely only one value is needed.

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers. It is kind of working now. However, I only get half of the string via the soft serial port. The part with the CO2 concentrations is missing. Any ideas why not the whole string is read in?